# The relation between uniform integrability and dominated convergence theorem in the case of counting measure

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I want to discover the analog between uniform integrability (UI) and the dominated convergence theorem (DCT) for infinite series.

An infinite series is an integral with respect to counting measure. That is, $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f(k)=\int_{\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}}f(k)\mu(dk),$ where $\mu$ is the counting measure.  We can then say a function $f$ is integrable with respect to the counting measure if $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|f(k)|=\int_{\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}}|f(k)|\mu(dk)<\infty.$

My first step is to reformulate DCT and UI.

For DCT, we are consider a sequence of $\mu-$integrable function $f_{n}(k)$ such that $f_{n}(k)\longrightarrow f(k)$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, and for each $n$, $|f_{n}(k)|\leq g(k)$ for some $\mu-$integrable $g(k)$. Then, $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f_{n}(k)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}(k)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f(k).$$

However, I don't know how to formulate the UI. The definition UI I have is that:

> A family $\{f_{\alpha\}}$ of integrable function is uniform integrable if for any $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that whenever $\lambda(A)<\delta$, $\sup_{\alpha}\int_{A}|f_{\alpha}|\lambda(dx)<\epsilon,$ where $\lambda$ here is a general measure.

I can reformulate this without problem, but I don't understand what does it mean for $\mu(A)<\delta$ when $\mu$ is a counting measure.

I read some online notes saying that DCT is a consequence of UI and Egoroff Theorem, I understand this, since Egoroff will give you a set $A$ on which the convergence is uniform and UI can make the integral on $A^{c}$ to be negligible. But this requires the measure space to be finite. I am not sure if we can apply this to counting measure, i.e. is $(\mathbb{N},\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}),\mu)$ a finite measure space?

Even I can answer this question, I don't want to stop here.I believe that  there must be something special in the case of counting measure, since $\mu(A)<\delta$ in the case of counting measure is still mysterious to me, but for now I don't know where to continue.

Thank you!

---

**Edit: Example**

Okay, I worked some examples, but I still don't quite understand what fails.

For example, consider the sequence $f_{n}(x)$ on the integer $X:=\{1,2,3,\cdots\}$, defined by
$$f_{n}(x)=\left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
\frac{1}{n},\ \ \text{if}\ \ x=1,2,\cdots, n\\
0,\ \ \text{if}\ \ x\geq n+1.
\end{array}
\right.$$

Note that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_{n}(x)=1$ for every $n$, but $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}(x)=0$ for every $x$, so we cannot interchange the limit and summation.

As suggested by the comment, uniform integrability is guaranteed in the case of counting measure, so What fails here?

---

**Edit: Potential Answer**

As Rivers Mcforge said, the example above does not satisfy the boundedness requirement in DCT. Along with the comment of Lorenzo, I found a connection between the boundedness requirement and tightness.

As Lorenzo suggested, the sequence in above example is not $\mu-$tight, and since we are over an infinite measure space, the Vitali convergence theorem needs the tightness. (The uniform integrability was given to us for free over our space, as suggested by both answers below).

Eventually, I found that in the case of our counting measure space, a sequence that satisfies DCT will also satisfy Vitali. In other words, we can use Vitali to prove DCT (in the case of our counting measure space $(\mathbb{N},\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}),\mu)$).

Indeed, recall that for any measure $\lambda$ and any measurable set $E$ (not necessarily of finite measure), if $f$ is $\lambda-$integrable over $E$, then for each $\epsilon>0$, there is a set of finite measure $E_{0}$ for which $$\int_{E\setminus E_{0}}|f(x)|\lambda(dx)<\epsilon.$$

Now, suppose $f_{n}(x)$ is an sequence of functions on $X$ that converges $\mu-$almost surely to $f(x)$. It is for free that $f_{n}(x)$ is uniformly integrable. If $|f_{n}(x)|\leq g(x)$ for all $n$ and $x$, where $g(x)$ is $\mu-$integrable, then by the above recalled fact, for each $\epsilon>0$, there is a subset $X_{0}$ of $X$ of finite measure for which $$\int_{E\setminus E_{0}}|f_{n}(x)|\mu(dx)\leq \int_{E\setminus E_{0}}|g(x)|\mu(dx)<\epsilon,\ \text{for all}\ n.$$ Hence, the family $\{f_{n}(x)\}$ is tight.

Then, it follows from Vitali that we can interchange the summation (the $\mu-$integral) with the limit of $n\rightarrow\infty.$ Thus, the confusion of DCT follows.

I am not sure if tightness can conversely imply the boundedness requirement in DCT.

Comment: Your example $f_n(x)$ fails DCT: any $g$ satisfying $g(x) \geq |f_n(x)|$ for all $x, n$ must in particular satisfy $g(n) \geq f_n(n) \geq 1/n$, and $g(n) = 1/n$ isn't integrable on all of $\Bbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$.

Comment: @RiversMcForge get it! Thanks for your explanation!! I finally figure out the reason behind. Will edit in a minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Is $(\mathbb{N},P(\mathbb{N}),\mu)$ a finite measure space?" It is not. I think this is basically the problem , since with the counting measure you could take $\delta = 1/2$ for all $\epsilon$, and then the condition is vacuous true, while if you take any finite measure subset convergence issues go away.

If you want to work with non-finite measure spaces, you need this theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem

A good example to think about is the sequence of sequences $(1_{n})_{n \geq 1}$ ( a point mass moving towards infinity).

Another good example is to consider the sequence of sequences, where the $nth$ sequence is $\alpha_n = \frac{1}{n} ( 1,\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \ldots, \frac{1}{2^{n^2}}, 0 ,0 ,\ldots)$. What does Vitali's convergence theorem say about this?

Comment: okay, by your suggestion, what I can show is that in the case of our counting measure $\mu$, since any $\mu-$integrable function is automatically UI, we can use Vitali to prove that DCT is an immediate consequence. But I am not sure what happens to my example added in the post, in that example, we cannot swap the infinite sum (the integral) and the limit. I guess it violates the second requirement of Vitali? I am not sure

Comment: @JacobsonRadical It is indeed the second requirement that is the issue here, though to be fair the wikipedia-definition is a bit unnecessarily hard to read. Roughly speaking it translates to "the bulk of the functions live on the same set of finite measure". If your measure is already finite, this becomes trivial. Fundamentally the two obstacles to exchanging limit and integral are always concentrations and "runaway support". UI blocks the former while the latter is what happens in your counterexample.

Comment: @mlk I also read more about this. So by the "concentration", you actually mean the tightness requirement, right? So basically my example up there is not tight with respect to the counting measure, it is not really concentrated. But I am not sure how to prove it rigorously.

Comment: @mlk nevertheless, I can now see the real connection between DCT and Vitali in our case. If we have the boundedness condition in DCT, then the family is tight, and thus we can have the vitali to work. If we don't have that boundedness condition in DCT, then the tightness does not come for free. I will edit the post.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Concentration is the name usually reserved for the opposite phenomenon, i.e. your sequence getting ever larger in an ever smaller set. If you have already encountered tightness of measures, then yes, this is precisely what is happening here, your sequence $f_nd\mu$ is not tight.

Comment: @mlk thank you so much! Yeah now I get the idea. I will update the post in a min

Comment: @mlk Just edited the post. I am not sure if I can advance more. Would you mind taking a look?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Are you asking in your update whether there is a sequence of functions where Vitali implies convergence but where DCT does not? I think an example is given by $f_n : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ which is $1/n$ on $n$ and zero everywhere else.

Comment: Oh. Okay. Nice! I was actually asking if my argument looks correct and the question you suggested. So in our counting measure space, we can use Vitali to prove DCT, and even though sometimes the assumption in DCT does not hold, we can still use Vitali. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JacobsonRadical The boundedness -> tightness part seems right. However, note that in general almost sure convergence doesn't imply convergence in measure. (The example of a mass moving to infinity -- although over probability spaces almost sure convergence does imply convergence in measure/ in probability.) Convergence in measure is a hypothesis for Vitali, so there's a step missing from your argument. You can fix it though - Vitali does imply DCT.

Comment: @LorenzoNajt I just check Royden page 98 for the general Vitali theorem (so E can be infinite measure), it seems that UI+tightness+almost surely convergence is enough. Perhaps the tightness gives us the sufficiency of almost surely convergence.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical I think it is the case that being dominated by g + a.e convergence implies convergence in measure. At least for the counting measure, the main idea should be similar to the other argument you wrote out -- for every $\epsilon$, you can find some large $N$ where $|f_n| \leq g(n) < \epsilon$ for $n > N$, and then on the finite piece $[0,N]$ you can get them all close to the target (say the $0$ sequence, for simplicity). I guess a similar argument works with the right conditions on your measure space.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical The key to use almost surely convergence is usually Egorov and you indeed need the tightness. The full proof is a bit to large for a comment and possibly another question, but the basic idea is to first use tightness to get to a finite measure subset and then Egorov to get uniform convergence on a subset of this. Now the set on which $|f_n-f|$ is large can only consist of the leftover from Egorov, (which is small) and a part thrown out by tightness, on which $\int |f_n| d\mu$ is small, which implies that the subsets, where $|f_n|$ are $|f|$ are large, are small.

Comment: @mlk right. Thanks for your detailed explanation!! I checked the book, the proof do carries the same idea as yours. Thank you :)

Comment: @mlk By the way, I think the intuition that you offered in your earlier comments about the conditions of Vitali convergence would greatly improve the wikipedia page. Please edit them in if you have the time! (I can do it, but would rather give someone with greater expertise the opportunity to do so first.)

Answer (score 3):

If you strictly follow the definition, **any** integrable family of functions on $\Bbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ should be uniformly integrable with respect to [counting measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure), since $\delta = 1$ works for any $\epsilon > 0$, as a set of measure less than $1$ must have measure $0$.

Comment: Can you provide more details regarding your ideas? Thank you.

Comment: @Mike the counting measure is defined to be the cardinality of the set, and in the our case you cannot have a set of cardinality less than $1$ but is not $0$.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I just add an example in my post, do you know what fails in the example so that although we have UI but the limit and sum cannot be interchanged?

Comment: I commented. The example does not satisfy DCT.

Comment: @RiversMcForge thank you so much. I just edited the post, I finally saw the connection.